# Why is the reference of structs with similar first members allowed despite C strict aliasing rules?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

*First, I apologize if this appears to be a duplicate, but I couldn't find exactly this question elsewhere*

I was reading through [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), specifically §6.5¶7, which reads:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>   —  a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   —  a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   —  a type  that  is  the  signed  or  unsigned  type  corresponding  to  the  effective  type  of  the object,
>   —  a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>   —  an aggregate  or  union  type  that  includes  one  of  the  aforementioned  types  among  its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>   —  a character type.

This reminded me of a common idiom I had seen in (BSD-like) socket programming, especially in the [`connect()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) call. Though the second argument to `connect()` is a `struct sockaddr *`, I have often seen passed to it a `struct sockaddr_in *`, which appears to work because they share a similar initial element. My question is:

**To which contingency detailed in the above rule does this situation apply and why, or is it now undefined behavior that's an artifact of previous standard(s)?**

Comment: I've been planning a similar question for weeks, though a little different.

Comment: Jens Gustedt explains it in his blog how such code is only valid if the `struct sockaddr_in` in use is in dynamic memory (and thus amenable to being retyped by the last access) or in a union: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2016/08/17/effective-types-and-aliasing/?blogsub=confirming#blog_subscription-3 . Practically though, even without dynamic memory or unions, the code will work, because the POSIX functions will be in separate compilation units where the compiler can't (without link time optimizations) see what the effective type is and so is prevented from strict-aliasing-based optimization.

Comment: @PSkocik: The authors of the Effective Type Rules have never, so far as I can tell, had a consensus understanding of which corner cases should be treated as having defined behavior.  Implementations intended for low-level programming should support more low-level constructs than those intended exclusively for high-end number crunching, but the Standard recognizes no distinction between those different kinds of implementation.  So far as I can tell, the only compilers that perform correctly in all defined cases are those that make no effort to exploit all permissible optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules about common initial sequences goes back to 1974.  The earliest rules about "strict aliasing" only go back to 1989.  The intention of the latter was not that they trump everything else, but merely that compilers be allowed to perform optimizations *that their customers would find useful* without being branded non-conforming.  The Standard makes clear that in situations where one part of the Standard and/or an implementation's documentation would describe the behavior of some action but another part of the Standard would characterize it as Undefined Behavior, implementations may opt to give priority to the first, and the Rationale makes clear that the authors thought "the marketplace" would be better placed than the Committee to determine when implementations should do so.

Under a sufficiently pedantic reading of the N1570 6.5p7 constraints, almost all programs violate them, but in ways that won't matter unless an implementation is being sufficiently obtuse.  The Standard makes no attempt to list all the situations in which an object of one type may be accessed by an lvalue of another, but rather those where a compiler must allow for an object of one type to be accessed by a *seemingly unrelated* lvalue of another.  Given the code sequence:

```
int x;
int *p[10];
p[2] = &someStruct.intMember;
...
*p[2] = 23;
x = someStruct.intMember;
```

In the absence of the rules in 6.5p7, unless a compiler kept track of where `p[2]` came from, it would have no reason to recognize that the read of `someStruct.member` might be targeting storage that was just written using `*p[2]`.  On the other hand, given the code:

```
int x;
int *p[10];
...
someStruct.intMember = 12;
p[2] = &someStruct.intMember;
x = *p[2];
```

Here, there is no rule that would actually allow the storage associated with a structure to be accessed by an lvalue of that member type, but unless a compiler is being deliberately blind, it would be able to see that after the first assignment to `someStruct.intMember`, the address of that member is being taken, and should either:

1. Account for all actions that will ever be done with the resulting pointer, if it is able to do so, or
2. Refrain from assuming that the structure's storage will not be accessed between the previous and succeeding actions using the structure's type.

I don't think it ever occurred to the people who were writing the rules that would later be renumbered as N1570 6.5p7 that they would be construed so as to disallow common patterns that exploited the Common Initial Sequence rule.  As noted, most programs violate the constraints of 6.5p7, but do so in ways that would be processed predictably by any compiler that isn't being obtuse; those using the Common Initial Sequence guarantees would have fallen into that category.  Since the authors of the Standard recognized the possibility of a "conforming" compiler that was only capable of meaningfully processing one contrived and useless program, the fact that an obtuse compiler could abuse the "aliasing rules" wasn't seen as a defect.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is not defined by the C standard.

The behavior is defined by The Single Unix Specification and/or other documents relating to the software you are using, albeit in part implicitly.

The phrasing that “An object **shall** have its stored value accessed only by…” is misleading. The C standard cannot compel you to do anything; you are not obligated to obey its “shall” requirements. In terms of the C standard, the only consequence of not obeying its requirements is that the C standard does not define the behavior. This does not prohibit other documents from defining the behavior.

In [the `netinet/in.h` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/netinetin.h.html), we see “The **sockaddr_in** structure is used to store addresses for the Internet protocol family. Values of this type must be cast to **struct sockaddr** for use with the socket interfaces defined in this document.” So the documentation tells us not only that we should, but that we must, convert a `sockaddr_in` to a `sockaddr`. The fact that we must do so implies that the software supports it and that it will work. (Note that the phrasing is imprecise here; we do not actually cast a `sockaddr_in` to a `sockaddr` but actually convert the pointer, causing the `sockaddr_in` object in memory to be treated as a `sockaddr`.)

Thus there is an implied promise that the operating system, libraries, and developer tools provided for a Unix implementation support this.

This is an extension to the C language: Where behavior is not defined by the C standard, other documents may provide definitions and allow you to write software that cannot be written using the C standard alone. Behavior that the C standard says is *undefined* is not behavior that is prohibited but rather is an empty space that may be filled in by other specifications.

Comment: Your last sentence makes UB sound less dangerous than it is. Can you say something like "Behavior that the C standard says is *undefined* is an empty space that may be filled in by other specifications, and is only prohibited if it is not filled in" instead?

Comment: Very good answer: unfortunately I only have one check mark. :(

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: “Prohibited” would be the wrong word. There is no prohibition. While the C standard describes “shall” as a requirement and “shall not” as a prohibition (C 2018 4 1), these are language tools **within** the standard. They are not, and cannot be, prohibitions outside the standard—they cannot prohibit a person from doing something. Consider that, if they did, there would be no difference in them based on whether something else defined the behavior or did not, and that would mean you would be prohibited from using behavior defined by the compiler but not the standard.

Comment: What I mean is that if the standard says something is UB, and the system implementer doesn't specify something of their own, then the application programmer is prohibited from doing that thing. Is that accurate?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: No. Who is prohibiting it? The C standard is voluntary; it has no power to compel. The compiler? You can feed it anything you want. The program loader or the operating system? You can try anything you want, and they will respond as they will. But they cannot stop you from trying. If you have a contract or an employer, they might prohibit you from doing something. Or if what you are doing so wrong it is illegal, then there could be a law against it, like accessing a system without permission. Otherwise, there is no prohibition.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: This whole notion that software specifications say what you may or may not do is off track. Software specifications govern software, not people. They say what the software will do when it is given this or that source code, input, or other data. You could say “**If** I want defined behavior, **then** I must not do **X**.” But that is a choice the programmer (or their employer or contractor) makes; it is a prohibition only if they opt into it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Quoting the authors of the C Standard at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf page 11, lines 33-36: "Undefined behavior gives the implementor license not to catch certain program errors that are difficult to diagnose. **It also identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior.**" Earlier on the page, they say they regard support for such "popular extensions" as a Quality of Implementation issue best left to the marketplace.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Actually, the Standard explicitly says "shall" and "shall not" are not used to specify requirements or prohibitions for programs that do not seek to be *strictly* conforming.  Conforming implementations must issue a diagnostic if translation-time constraints are violated, but are allowed to usefully process programs that violate translation-time or runtime constraints.  Violation of contraints will prevent a program from being *strictly* conforming, but will not necessarily make it non-conforming.